# TROUBLE WITH CODE -> Python recognizing faces in a newspaper

Tags: python, opencv, python-imaging-library, tesseract

My assignment is to iterate through a zipfile containing some images, each image is a page of the newspaper, and the goal is to search for a word in a page and display all faces recognized in that page.

I'm storing the data in a dictionary, which keys are the names of the image files and the values are, first the text generated by pytesseract and second is the ZipInfo object for that image.

The function to generate the dictionary is working just fine, as it generates what I want, but the problem is in the other two functions, wordCheck() and detectFaces(), as an empty list is being returned

Here is the code:

```
def getDict(zippedFile):
    '''
    This function gets a .zip file containing images and returns a dictionary whose keys are the image names
    and the values are the images text content.
    '''
    j = 0
    i = 0
    dic = {}
    contents = []
    imageObject = []
    with zipfile.ZipFile(zippedFile) as file:
        for single_info in file.infolist():
            imageObject.append(single_info)
            with file.open(single_info) as imageInfo:
                img = Image.open(imageInfo)
                text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
                contents.append(text)
    for name in file.namelist():
        dic[name] = [contents[j], imageObject[j]]
        j += 1

    return dic

def detectFaces(imageName, dic):
    '''
    This function gets and image name, that is in a .zip file and returns a list containing bounding boxes for
    faces detected on the given image.
   '''
    boundingBoxes = []
    with zipfile.ZipFile('readonly/small_img.zip') as file:
        imageInfo = dic[imageName][1]
        PILImage = Image.open(imageInfo)
        display(PILImage)
        img = cv.imread(PILImage)
        gray = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        print(gray)
        faceBoxes = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray)

    for item in faceBoxes:
        print(item)
        boundingBoxes.append(item[0])

    return boundingBoxes

def checkWord(word, dic):
    '''

    '''
    bBoxes = []
    for key in dic:
        if word in dic[key]:
            print('Results found in {}'.format(key))
            bBoxes.append(detectFaces(key, dic))
    return bBoxes 


dictera = getDict('readonly/small_img.zip')
result = checkWord('Senator', dictera)
print(result)
```

I'm very newbie in programming, so if I made a silly mistake, pardon me!
I have no idea on what to try next, do you guys have a clue for what's going on?

Comment: please read the guidelines to how produce a minimal example of your problem so the users here could help you. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Had some other problems and already solved them, but figured out I was returning a list which is never mentioned. Duur!